# Ruby on rails: error in sending xml message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I try to send a xml file to a web service, but it's not working. The web service supplier has no idea.

If you read the error message, it looks like there is a wrong soap version used, but the supplier tried it with the same xml file and he had no problems with this file. I have no idea what's wrong.

The code:

```
#Declaration
host     = "bar.foo.nl";
path     = "/services/setu.asmx";
port     = 443;
username = "xxx"
password = "yyy";
ssl      = true; 

#Create connection
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(path)
req.basic_auth(username, password)

http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
http.use_ssl = ssl


#send file
res = http.request(req, 'D:/test.xml')

#show result
puts res.code
puts res.body
```

EDIT: The xml file: [XML FILE](http://we.tl/00OhaHpv3Z)

The error (500 code):

> Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace
>   http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15 was unexpected. Expecting
>   http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.

Comment: Is there a soap namespace defined in your file?

Comment: Yes there is, I uploaded the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any soap declarations in the file you've uploaded, and it looks like the service you're contacting requires it.

Start with http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp and rework your content to be wrapped in a soap envelope.

Comment: I added an envelope, header and body and get this error: "">Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.", but I have no idea where I can find this action.

Comment: That's progress, the action is where the request needs to go once it is received, like a method name. The web service provider should be able to give you the available options.